# Symfony 4 catch vue-resource post withe mulitpart-form

Tags: php, symfony, vuejs2, vue-resource

How to get $_file withe SF4 ?

```
var_dump($request->request->all());
```

return my formdate without my field File, 
but in $_FILES is full

I can't make :

```
$fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
```

Obtain fatal error

> Call to a member function guessExtension() on null

My request seem to bee good with my formData.

How to resolve this error ? 
thx

Answer (score 0):

You can access request's files by doing this

```
$request->files->all()
```

Usually in Symfony, your file is part of an entity property and your form use this entity so you can write something like this

```
$myEntity->getFile()
```